# grouping attributes in RF and GBM

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, boosting

i have a dataset with 1000 samples and ~11k features (SNP markers). i have identified 100 additional binary features describing the markers themselves so i have a `100 x 11000` matrix describing various marker attributes (in fact frequent patterns from various relational data associated to the SNPs in question). i would like to 'enhance' the original attributes matrix with this additional information and run random forest and boosted trees on the augmented data. however, this would involve introducing extra 100 features (essentially dummy variables) per each marker so i would end up with `11*10^5` attributes in total.

it would make sense to consider each group of additional 100 features (associated to each one marker) together. if one wishes to use a linear model one can, for example, employ grouped lasso for this purpose. **what about random forests (RF) and boosted trees (GBM)? has it been done before and if so does anyone know of an implementation in `R`?**

Comment: Are the binary features the result of one-hot encoding? That is to say, could you turn the 100 features into a categorical feature with 100 levels and not lose any information?

Comment: @Zelazny7 sorry for a mega-slow reply -- no, you can't turn `n` features into one feature with `n` levels. you can only turn it into one feature with `2^n` levels.